# Concatenate variable to a link in PHP

Tags: php, json

I would like to link a variable to a link.
The variable looks something like this which I grab from json.
The json variable for `$movieSeat` is : `A1,A2,B3,V4`

Below is the code that I've tried out.
The issue that I am currently having is, the link doesn't seem to be working. It seems like something to do with `.` and `+`.
I'm also not too sure when to use `.` and `+` for the linking.

```
<?php
    echo "<script> function movieBTN(x) { location.href = 'http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=" . $movieSeat. "'; } </script>";       
    for ($i = 0; $i < $jsonCounter; $i++) {
    $movieSeat =  $jsonValue[$i]->seatID;      
    echo "<button onclick = movieBTN(".$movieSeat.")> Movie Seat </button>";        
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Your code seems correct, in PHP you use `.` for concatenation.

Comment: I can't understand, why the button is not working, since the concatenation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you're echoing the function from PHP, make sure you use JS variables and not PHP's:

```
echo "<script> function movieBTN(x) { location.href = 'http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' + x; } </script>";
```

So it will output:

```
<script> 
    function movieBTN(x) { location.href = 'http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' + x; } 
</script>
```

Next, you need to wrap the variable passed to that function with `'`:

```
echo "<button onclick = movieBTN('".$movieSeat."')> Movie Seat </button>";
```

So it will output as:

```
<button onclick = movieBTN('A1')> Movie Seat </button>
```

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work. 
When I click on the button, it doesn't do anything

Comment: @jamie try changing it to `echo "<button onclick = movieBTN('".$movieSeat."')> '".$movieSeat."' </button>"; ` - Can you see the actual expected value wrapped with `'` (Example: `'A1'`) ?

Comment: yes, but it's not working, as in it doesn't move to another link , like http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=A1

Comment: @jamie And did you copy&paste the first line in my code, where you echo the JS function? Note that it's different then yours. Try `echo "<script> function movieBTN(x) { alert( 'http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' + x); } </script>";` - Do you get an alert when you click on the button
`